# Parameterized includes

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

In a few C programs (for example in [gecko](https://github.com/mozilla/gecko-dev/blob/aac3a947d7cb117cef0ebe5e7291c36b716125e6/gfx/harfbuzz/src/hb-shape-plan.cc#L68)) I've noticed an idiom whereby a program will temporarily define a macro, then include a file which uses that macro, then undefine the macro. Here's a trivial example:

speak.c:

```
#define SPEAK(phrase) (printf("When I speak I say %s\n", (phrase)))
#include "dog.h"
#undef SPEAK
```

dog.h:

```
SPEAK("woof");
```

Which expands to:

```
(printf("When I speak I say %s\n", ("woof")))
```

I gather this might be a useful technique to generalize included code by being able to specify behavior at the expansion site.

**Does this pattern have a name, or has it been written about previously?**

Comment: Pretty strange to use non-compiling code as an example, there's no `;` after the statement (and a statement in `()` makes little sense to me).

Comment: This is close/identical to the [X macro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro) concept.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth IMO that comment is answer worthy!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a good reference documenting patterns of use of X-Macros in C (or possibly C++)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/264269/what-is-a-good-reference-documenting-patterns-of-use-of-x-macros-in-c-or-possib), and there's also [Real-world use of X-Macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6635851/real-world-use-of-x-macros)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a variant of what are often called [X macros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro).

#### Further reading

- [*The New C: X Macros*](http://www.drdobbs.com/the-new-c-x-macros/184401387) (Dr Dobbs)